# concurrent UPDATE, make the other transactions fail when commiting

Tags: postgresql, transactions, sql-update

I have two programs PCrit and PLong reading/writing on the same tables using Postgres.

PCrit is really critical and should never fail/block.

PLong needs to read, compute and update a lot a things in a single transaction which can take minutes, but it can fail as long as all the changes are rolled back.

The rows have a status, and if the status is 'FIXED', PLong cannot update rows with this status.
PCrit can quickly update all the rows in a single query to 'FIXED' before working on only those rows in a second transaction.

In most of the cases PCrit and PLong don't updates the same rows. But it can happen if PLong takes too long to run.

If PCrit runs and update rows, I want PLong to fail to commit if it has touched any of the rows updated by PCrit.

I thought about using the repeatable read transaction level

Example:

1. PLong begins its repeatable read transaction
2. PCrit updates some rows status in a single query/transaction and commits
3. PLong updates some of the same rows
4. PCrit commits (fails with `could not serialize access due to concurrent update`)

The problem is when 2 and 3 are inverted, PCrit will block until PLong commits.
I would like PCrit not to block and be able to commit, and make PLong fail when committing instead.

Is it possible to do with Postgres?
Should I change my design to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that automatically.

You could use a very low `lock_timeout` for PCrit, and if you get a lock timeout error, go and kill PLong using `pg_cancel_backend`.